# How can I use Feeds to import flaggings with Flag 4.x?

Tags: 9, feeds, flags

I'm trying to set up the Feeds module to import flaggings with the Flag module on Drupal 9.  However, I keep getting errors.  What is the minimum necessary configuration to import flaggings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a feed of flaggings.
2. Add a mapping for **UID** and set the reference to User ID (drupal numeric ID) or UUID.
3. Add a mapping for **Entity Type** and make sure your source data has an entity type set (*node*, *taxonomy_term*, etc.)
4. Add a mapping for **Entity ID** and then use the numeric Drupal ID in your source data.  You cannot use a UUID for this at present.